# How to Combine Two Lists into Keys and Values and Add to Dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to turn list_A into keys and list_B into values. I would like to then attach these lists to the dictionary, dict_A.

For examples,

```
list_A = ['age', 'weight', 'height']

list_B = [21, 205, 72]

dict_A = {'name': 'hank'}
```

Desired output:

```
{'name': 'hank', 'age': 21, 'weight': 205, 'height': 72}
```

Thanks in advance for any help that you may offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a `dict` by pairing a list of `keys` and a list of `values` you may use `zip`

```
dict(zip(list_A, list_B))
```

Then use it to update `dict_A`

```
list_A = ['age', 'weight', 'height']
list_B = [21, 205, 72]
dict_A = {'name': 'hank'}
dict_A.update(dict(zip(list_A, list_B)))
```

Comment: Thank you @azro for your time! Much appreciated sir =) This code worked perfectly!